# A special idempotent function

Tags: functions, idempotents

Usually an idempotent function is $f: S \rightarrow S$ such that $f \circ f = f$.  But I need something slightly different:  $f: S \times S \rightarrow S$, such that:

For $x, y, z \in S$:

1. $f(x, y) = f(y, x)$  --- this is just commutativity
2. $f(x, x) = c(x)$ --- $c \,$ can be any function
3. $f(x, f(x,x)) = f(x,c(x)) = c(x)$ --- to guarantee idempotence
4. $f(x, f(y, z)) = f(f(x, y), z)$ --- associativity

In "infix" notation the requirements amounts to:

1. $x + y = y + x$
2. $x + x = c(x)$
3. $x + x + x  = x + c(x) = c(x)$
4. $x + (y + z) = (x + y) + z$

Under my definition, $f$ is *not* an idempotent function as it doesn't make sense to write $f \circ f$.

So I try to visualize the graph of $f(x,y)$.  Axiom 1 requires that the graph is symmetric along $x = y$.  Axiom 2 is automatically satisfied if $f$ is a single-valued function along $x = y$.

My problem is to understand axiom 3 (including its geometric interpretation).  What kind of constraint does it impose on $f$?

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to say another requirement is that 2 points will map to 1 point in the target space $T$.  I'm still thinking how to state this mathematically...

Comment: @Yan: I don't understand your requirements. If $f$ is a function $f : S \times S \to T$, what does the third requirement mean?

Comment: @Yan: if all you're looking for is functions that behave like set union, then you're looking for commutative idempotent monoids (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Examples). Examples are given by bounded semilattices (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice). But the corresponding operations are functions $f : S \times S \to S$.

Comment: Also, what does the metric have to do with anything?

Comment: I think you're right that I need commutative idempotent monoids (or bounded semilattices).  Is there an example where each lattice element is a  point in space?  I can only think of lattices whose elements are sets (not points).  I guess that's the real question...

Comment: PS:  I can think of "points" in a metric space, but not sure if in topological spaces, there is a distinction between point sets and a single point?

Comment: I don't understand. Sets have points. Why isn't $S$ just a set? A collection of sets is also a set.

Comment: If $S$ contains 2 of my points, then these 2 points may map to 2 separate points in $T$.  What I need is for the 2 points (from $S$) to map to a **single** point in $T$.

Comment: @julien: for a binary operation, idempotent means all elements are idempotent with respect to the binary operation, so $f(x, x) = x$. So we want $T = S$.

Comment: @Yan: that still doesn't have anything to do with the metric. I'm getting more and more confused about what you actually want. Do you know any examples of what you're looking for?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah, thanks. I had never encountered that.

Comment: julien:  perhaps it should be $f: S \times S \rightarrow S$.  The question remains whether there is a non-trivial $f$ that fits the requirements.

Comment: Yuan:  I don't know of any examples, that's why I'm asking :)  Basically the map needs to map 2 points to 1 point.

Comment: Seems that an example may be:  $ f(x,y) = (x,y) : x > y, \; (y,x) : x \le y$.